# Getting string from line and then pasting it to another in bash

Tags: linux, bash

From line:

`< div style="left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:63px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; background-color:#FCF0C4; border-color:#E87511; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; position:absolute;" >`

I want to get (values may be different)
`#FCF0C4`
and then paste it to another line

`< div  style="left:2px; top:32px; width:744px; height:27px; display:block; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; position:absolute; overflow:hidden; background-color:#ffffff;" >`

instead of

`#ffffff`

Comment: perhaps you would want to generate a css stylesheet instead

Comment: I have to make change I've described in about 100 css files. Making new stylesheets would be pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the color:

```
COL=$(echo '< div ... >' | sed -r 's/.*background-color:#([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,6});.*/#\1/')
```

Paste it into target:

```
echo '< div ... >' | sed -r 's/(.*background-color:#)([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,6})(;.*)/\1'$COL'\3/'
```

Result:

```
< div style="left:2px; top:32px; width:744px; height:27px; display:block; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; position:absolute; overflow:hidden; background-color:##FCF0C4;" >
```

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
sed 's/^.*background-color:\(#......\).*/s_background-color:#ffffff_background-color:\1_/' INFILE > TMPSED
  sed -if TMPSED ANOTHERFILE
```

Yet another solution with `awk` if they are in the same file. Identification of the lines might be regex, line number, etc.

```
awk '/IDENTIFY_YOUR_LINE_TO_COPY_COLOR/ { color=gensub(".*backround-color:(.......).*","\\1","g",$0) }
     /IDENTIFY_YOUR_LINE_TO_COPY_TO     {print gensub("^(.*backround-color:)#ffffff;(.*)","\\1" color "\\2","g",$0)}' INPUTFILE > OUTPUTFILE
```

Comment: In location of  '#FCF0C4' it may be various values (for example #FCFF24 etc). I want to get this value, and paste it to second line.

Answer (score 2):

Are you collecting these lines with `grep`? Or do you want the solution to do that? Is the line to change in the same file or a different one? Are there several files to edit? What determines which line to grab and which to edit? You are missing many important details for a *proper* solution.

Going off of what you have here:

```
TMPCOL=$(get line somehow | sed -r -n 's/background-color:#(.*);/\1/ p')
sed -i "s/background-color:#.*;/background-color:#$TMPCOL;/" fileToFix
```

Comment: There are many css files to edit. Both lines are in the same file. In every file you have to fetch colour value from first line and then paste it to second line which is somewhere in file. First line always looks like '< div style="left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:63px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; background-color:#FCF0C4; border-color:#E87511; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; position:absolute;" >'. One thing that is always diffrent is color value. Second line always is the same.

Comment: `.*;` will not work since sed is greedy and consumes anything up to the last semicolon.